# Ajax hits success callback before backend call finishes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I'm running into the following issue:

- an ajax call goes out to a backend jsp call
- sometimes(?) the success() callback on the ajax call is hit before the backend call finishes

I didn't think this was possible :)

The code looks something like this:

```
var opt =  {
    form: $form,
    retry: '0',
    retryHandler: function(...) { alert(...);},
    dataType: 'xml',
    url: url,
    error: function(xhr, status, e) { ... }
    timers: {},
    timeout: timingConfig.timeout,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { ... },
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        // breakpoint in here
    }
```

One breakpoint in success callback, and one breakpoint in the backend jsp. 
Both are hit at roughly the same time, where I'd expect success() to not be called until the the backend call finishes.

Any ideas on what's going on here? O_o

Comment: why there are two success functions in your code?

Comment: Use ajax({...}).done(function(){...}).fail(function(){....}); this will control. Anyway above code has two success statement please correct them.

Comment: @VIJAYABALDHANAPAL can you please explain how `ajax({...}).done(function(){...}).fail(function(){....});` will control?

Comment: Once your server returns response headers, the success (or error callback) is fired client side. We have no idea how you are checking that it could be different?! Maybe just your observation is wrong

Comment: Oops, right, too much copy pasta, there aren't really 2 success callbacks. I believe the code above was being hit from multiple locations, hence the confusion. I appreciate all the help though! I'll look into done() and fail() for future reference too. What's the correct way to close this? Delete the post? Answer my own question?